Show that if there are five points in a square with side length 1 metre, then there exist two of them which are less than 75 centimetres apart.
My attempt at trying to prove by contradiction:
I noticed that if such points existed then no three points would be collinear(since the maximum length a line can have in this square is is its diagonal). Hence it can be concluded that any of the three points form a triangle with side length of at least 75cm. Since there are 5 points, number of such triangles would be $5 \choose 3$ = $10$. However I can't make further progress rigorously. My idea is to show that the area of such a triangle would be at least $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}(75)^{2} \sim 2435$$
and since there are 10 such triangles the minimum possible area would exceed the area of the square($10000$cm^${2}$). How do I proceed from here?

see here
